# How do I find a pair in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was wondering how do I make a function that would return true if there's a pair in an array of 6 numbers? I tried to use this (the `sortThing`function is sorting the numbers array)

```
let arr = [];

this.sortThing();
for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
{
    for (let j = i + 1; j < numbers.length; j++)
    {
        while (arr.length < 5) 
        {
            if (arr.push(numbers[i] == numbers[j]))
                return numbers;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `arr.push` returns the length of the array after the push - does that sound right for your logic? since it will always be 1 or more (so true in an if)

Comment: Basically I am trying compare the value of the index so in this case `numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`  I am trying to find a pair,( I already have a randomizing method that returns my array in a different order) so for example I would get an array of [ 2,4,1,6,2,4] so my function should be returning true since there's at least on pair (a pair of 2 2's and a pair of 2 4's)

Comment: so, you just want true/false returned? `const haspairs = array => [... new Set(array)].length !== array.length;`

Comment: What if there be more than one duplicate number?  Which one(s) get reported?

Comment: yes I want true or false to be returned depending on the amount of pairs so if there's one pair of 2's or 4's I want it to return true if there's no pairs of 2's or 4's I want to return false. @Bravo

Answer (score 1):

I suggest sorting the array ascending, then walking down the array once looking for any array element to repeat:

```js
var numbers = [1, 5, 3, 7, 3];
numbers.sort((a, b) => a - b);
var pair = false;
var last = numbers[0];
for (var i=1; i < numbers.length; ++i) {
    if (last == numbers[i]) {
        pair = true;
        break;
    }

    last = numbers[i];
}

if (pair) {
    console.log("Array has a pair number: " + last);
}
else {
    console.log("No pair was found in the array.");
}
```

Comment: This is kind of what I am looking for although it's giving me the value that is paired and not the number of times that there's a pair found in the function. I did change it up a bit by removing the `break;` so i can get the number of times there's a pair, although it doesn't always work, when there's more than 2 pairs (sometimes it will show that there's just 1) 
(index)Value
0 2
1 4
2 1
3 4
4 2
5 4
Array has a pair number: 1

Comment: Your problem statement should reflect what you are trying to do.

Comment: I don't think I understand, can you rephrase it please?

Comment: @Bruhhh - I think Tim is expressing that it is unclear what it is you are seeking to do with this function.  In your question you state you want the function to simply return a Boolean indicating whether or not a pair is found.  This is what his approach does. 
 However, in your comment above you seem to suggest that you actually want the number of times a pair is found.  Your original post should clearly state your desired output-- there should not be adjustments made in comments spread around different posts.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: @AlexanderNied oh thank you for the clarification! I will try to be more clear next time.

Answer (score 1):

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4]
var firstelement
var checker = false

while (numbers.length>0) {
  firstelement = numbers[0]
  numbers.shift()
  if(numbers.indexOf(firstelement) !== -1){
    checker = true
    break
  }
}
console.log(checker)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const hasDuplicates = (arr) => {
  const set = new Set(arr);
  return set.size !== arr.length;
}
console.log(hasDuplicates([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247]))
```

Comment: `const arr = array.sort();` note, you are mutating the passed in array

Answer (score -1):

with a 6 digit array is easy to find duplicated using XOR

```js
const numbers = [1, 5, 3, 7, 3];
let y;
for(const x of numbers){
  y ^= x
}
console.log(y)
```